# re-raising an exception in a context handler

Tags: python, file, exception, resource-cleanup, contextmanager

From the [datamodel docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__) on context managers:

> Note that `__exit__()` methods should not reraise the passed-in exception; this is the caller’s responsibility.

---

I have a temporary file, whose file descriptor I'd like to free with `close` but without writing anything to disk. My intuitive solution was to pass on the exception, but that is [discouraged in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__) - and surely for good reasons.

```
class Processor(object):
    ...
    def write(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if something_bad_happens:
            raise RuntimeError('This format expects %s columns: %s, got %s.' % (
                               (len(self.cols), self.cols, len(args))))
        self.writer.writerow(args)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        # the RuntimeError from write will be set as type, value and so on ..
        # I'd like to close the stream here (release the file descriptor), 
        # but I do not leave a trace of the associated file - 
        # (one can always 'manually' delete with `os.remove` but maybe there's a 
        # better way ..?)
        self.output_pipe.close()
```

Also I do not want in this particular case error handling in the caller for two reasons:

- to keep the code in the caller minimal (see below)
- the caller is happy with exceptions (fail fast is what we want here)

The context manager is used something like this:

```
class Worker(object):
    ...
    def run(self):
        # output setup so it will emit a three column CSV
        with self.output().open('w') as output:
            output.write('John', 'CA', 92101)
            output.write('Jane', 'NY', 10304)
            # should yield an error, since only three 'columns' are allowed 
            output.write('Hello', 'world')
```

---

update: My quesion was a bit ill-formulated as my problem really boiled down to this: In nested context managers, how can I pass an exception on to the outermost CM?

Comment: Did you really mean to close the output twice in `__exit__`?

Comment: @user2357112, there's more code that I haven't included here - so the code might look terse and maybe difficult to contextualize, sorry for that. Updated my question, I do not close `output_pipe` twice.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- When `__exit__` returns True, any exception passed to it is swallowed.
- When `__exit__` returns False, the exception is reraised.

---

```
def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
    self.output_pipe.close()  # always close the file
    if type is not None: # an exception has occurred
        os.unlink(...)   # remove the file
        return False     # reraise the exception
```

You could of course omit the `return False` since Python will return `None` (which is Falsish) by default.

---

By the way, is `self.output()` an instance of `Processor`? If so,

```
with self.output().open('w') as output:
```

should be

```
with self.output() as output:
```

In any case, it would be nicer if you could arrange for the latter to be the correct syntax. You might have to change `__enter__` to:

```
def __enter__(self):
    return self.output_pipe.open('w')
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess the `return False` is just want I searched for.

Comment: @miku: *Any* falsey value will do; `None` included; not explicitly returning means `None` is returned and the exception remains raised.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I see. I find the explicit `False` a bit more reabable at the moment. I have to check the standard library for conventions on this...

Answer (score 3):

There is **no** need to `raise` the exception; the exception has *already* been raised and your context manager is merely being informed of that.

Test if there was *no* exception instead:

```
if type is None:
    # if no exception is raised, proceed as usual:
    self.output_pipe.close()
```

If your context manager were to return `True` at that moment you'd suppress the exception; just exiting the function instead returns `None` and the exception remains 'raised'.

Note that the [`tempfile` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) includes two types of temporary file objects that act as context managers, that self-delete *already*, independent of platform. On POSIX systems you can unlink the file right after creation; the file descriptor remains alive until you close the file. Windows offers a 'delete on close' option too. The `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()` class uses the right option for your platform.

Comment: That looks good and would do what I want, but does it free the resource (file descriptor) of the `output_pipe` which at that moment is an open file in `w` mode?

Comment: @miku: It appears your code calls `self.output_pipe.close()` **twice**; the second time only when you did not encounter an exception. I merely showed how to handle exceptions.

Comment: @user2357112: I was demonstrating *how* you'd test if you needed to.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, no I do not close the `output_pipe` twice, I was just show the two variants (one with and one without error checking).

Comment: @miku: Right, you don't *need* error checking in this case then. Just clean up *regardless* of the exception being raised. That is what a context manager is *for*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I realize now, that my question is a bit incomplete. Thanks anyway for your answer.